# BeforePrint Event is Firing without Printing

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below. It makes me wonder why the **BeforePrint** event in the workbook codes is fired even though I am not printing anything. The workbook definitely is not blank. The error is in the creation of the PDF file.

The file does a simple job of saving the worksheet in a PDF format with the name of the sheet, the file path of the workbook, and some details inside the worksheet.

Anything that I am missing? I am not new to VBA but this bugs me a lot today. I am using MS Excel 2016 on Windows 7 ultimate.

Edit: I tried removing the following codes below but the problem still persists:

```
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

The code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub createpdffile()

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim sheetname As String, sheetcode As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer

'temporarily disable error handler so that I can see where the bug is.
'On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
wbA.Save
'get last row of sheet and set print area to last row with L column
iRow = wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
wsA.PageSetup.PrintArea = wsA.Range("A1:L" & iRow).Address

'just checking name in sheet and removing needed characters
sheetname = wsA.Name
openPos = InStr(sheetname, "(")
closePos = InStr(sheetname, ")")
sheetcode = Mid(sheetname, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'create default name for saving file
strFile = sheetcode & " No. " & wsA.Cells(11, 9) & " - " & wsA.Cells(8, 3) & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS LOCATED
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file" & vbNewLine & _
    "Please complete the details needed!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error Saving as PDF"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

---

Solution from [Foxfire and Burns and Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199828/foxfire-and-burns-and-burns)' idea:

I added a public declaration before the main sub.

```
Option Explicit

'added line
Public myboolean as Boolean 

Public Sub createpdffile()

myboolean = True


....
```

Then I added a line in the BeforePrint Event that says:

```
If myboolean = True Then Exit Sub
```

This now bypasses the BeforePrint event when the virtual PDF printer is called.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: BTW, the default value of this myboolean variable is TRUE, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, default value is 0, that means false. Why? Because normally boolean data "activates" when a condition is met. Most usual thing is that, by default, when you initialize a code, that condition is not met, so boolean variables are false by default

Comment: Greatly thankful for this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat
```

That line activates the BeforePrint Event. Actually, you are printing a PDF file. It works as a virtual PDF Printer.

Comment: Is that how it is? OMG! Are there suggested workarounds to this? I would like to force my client to save the PDF, therefore I restricted him to print directly in workbooks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand right. You want your client to export the file as a PDF, but you don't want the code of BeforePrint event to get executed?

Comment: Yes, it is what I want. Is exporting file as PDF exactly printing it as PDF? If this is the case, then my idea is impossible. :(

Comment: Not sure if it is EXACTLY like printing, but it does indeed activates the BeforePrint event, so I would say, yes it is. Delete the code in BeforePrint Event, or use a Public Variable Boolean Type that activates only if that client opens the workbooks. Something like IF MyBooleanVariable=true then exit sub and add it to BeforePrint Event